# Is it possible to set content related permissions on cartalyst/sentinel?

Tags: laravel, authentication, laravel-5, authorization, cartalyst-sentinel

i'm new to laravel and cartalyst/sentinel, but for this project i'm facing out an authorization problem: 
I have to set User CRUD permissions for the single content, and i'm facing out how to do id with cartalyst/sentinel.
(a lil' example: if i have a blog, i wanna set User CRUD permissions separately for each article).
Can anyone help me to find some documentation about something like this?
I have already implemented this kind of permissions with CakePHP, but is the first time i'm using laravel.
Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the last seems noone never has been capable to solve this problem, and i cant test the solution proposed. So i've falled back to the ACL stock support of Laravel 5.0. 
Baybe i'll retry when i need the multisession system or other things from sentinel.

Answer (score 1):

The way I think you'd best go about this is by setting the users permission by using the article ID. You could give a user permissions like this: `"articles.14.read":1,"articles.24.*":1`. 14 & 24 being IDs of articles I made up.